# populate table where each column comes from a different line of a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a txt file where some lines contain strings and some other lines contain values.The values correspond"belong" to the previous line.For example:

```
+'aaa'
+'bbb'
*value1
*value2
+'ccc'
*value3
+'ddd'
```

etc.
I am trying to create a table where the first column has the lines that contain the strings and the second column has the lines that contain the values.My problem is that I want, if the string has a corresponding value(s),the string and the values(list) to be in the same row.If the string doesn't have a corresponding value, I want it to be in the same row with NULL.Something like this:

```
column1  |      column2
-----------------------------
+'aaa'    |   NULL
+'bbb'    | [*value1 ,*value2]
+'ccc'    | [*value3]
+'ddd'    |   NULL
    etc
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
import sqlite3
db=sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
cur=db.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE mytable (mystrings TEXT, myvalues TEXT)')
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith('+'):
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?))",line)
        if line.startswith('*'):
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?))",line)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

but obviously this isn't right because mytable takes two values.

Comment: And what is the question? What problem do you have in your code?

Comment: I tried to do something like this:
import sqlite3
db=sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
cur=db.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE mytable (mystrings TEXT, myvalues TEXT)')

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith('+'):
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?))",line)
        if line.startswith('*'):
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?))",line)
but obviously this isn't right because mytable takes two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply insert values as soon as you find them. At least you should insert a line with only `mystrings` column, and then update when you find `myvalues`. But as you may have more than one value per string, it is as simple to store the key and the values and do one single insert :

```
import sqlite3

def createtable(dbname):
    db=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    cur=db.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE mytable (mystrings TEXT, myvalues TEXT)')
    cur.close()
    db.close()


def dropdb(dbname):
    db=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    cur=db.cursor()
    cur.execute('DROP TABLE mytable')
    cur.close()
    db.close()

def insert(cur, key, val):
    if key is not None:
        if len(val) == 0:
                value = None
        elif len(val) == 1:
                value = val[0]
        else:
                value = str(val)
        # print "INSERT", key, value
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?, ?)", (key, value))

def trt(filename, dbname):
    key = None
    val = None
    db = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    cur = db.cursor()
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith('+'):
                    if  key is not None:
                        if len(val) == 0:
                            value = None
                        elif len(val) == 1:
                            value = val[0]
                        else:
                            value = str(val)
                        insert(cur, key, val)
                    print "key", line[:-1]
                    key = line[:-1]
                    val = []
                else:
                    print "value", line[:-1]
                    if val is None:
                        print "Value before first string : ignored"
                    else:
                    val.append(line[:-1])
        insert(cur, key, val)
    finally:
        cur.close()
        db.commit()
        db.close()

createdb('mydatabase.db')
trt('myfile.txt', 'mydatabase.db')
```

Comment: Thank you!!But I'm afraid I have a problem.I ran the script the first time,and it created the database just as it was supposed to.But when I tried to run it again,I got this:    in trt val.append(line[:-1])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment       ,and the database is empty.I can't understand what's wrong.I didn't change anything in the code the second time.I ran it multiple times and it's always the same,I get an error and an empty database...   p.s. I believe it is createtable('mydatabase.db') in the second to last line

Comment: Couldn't it be that first line begins with a '*' ? But anyway, the script has not been written to be repeteadly called at it creates the table. If table exists you get `OperationalError: table mytable already exists`. But I've just added a test to give a more informational message

Comment: I guess it could be the '*'. I'll replace it and try it again.Your code is flawless,so I must be doing something wrong and i just haven't noticed it yet.Besides,it already ran once.Anyway,what's important is that I understand now how to populate a table from a txt file.Thank you so much!!!